# using Outlook 2007 addin ribbon

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook-addin

I am developing an add in for MS Outlook 2007 using VSTO 2008.

I need to add user-friendly design for it using the Ribbon (which is provided by VSTO 2008 office addins).

I need to load form in that menu button and need to apply a ribbon for that form.

I already add ribbon and new form to outlook addin, I need to know how I can connect to the ribbon with form which I need to decorate

How can I do it please help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking about how to add a ribbon to a form. In that case, you would need a ribbon control on the form (maybe use WPF instead?) In the ribbon control, just add your pre-designed ribbon via code or using the designer.